# Navigating through different activities in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Hey people I would like to know how to check if from which activity my current activity has been opened from. A small uncomplicated example:

I have three activities A B C

And I have a textview in B

When I open my activity B from A, I want the text view to display hello but when I open in from c to say goodbye.

If this is possible please assist

NB beginner in Android 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Intent like this while opening activity  `startActivity(new Intent(context,B.class).putExtra("from","ActivityA"));` and in the final activity get the intent data to know which activity has started it.

Comment: @SaravInfern putStringExtra doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

```
For A to B:

startActivity(new Intent(A.this,B.class).putExtra("value","Hello");
In B.java get those values by:
String value=getIntent().getStringExtra("value");

Similarly for C to B:

startActivity(new Intent(C.this,B.class).putExtra("value","goodbye");
In B.java get those values by:
String value=getIntent().getStringExtra("value");
```